# How can i insert current date as a value in an input form field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was able to get a current date with java in the format i wanted and actually expect it to be displayed as text value in the input field.
I dont want to use the type="date" to select. 
any heads up or how current date can be inserted as a value in the input field. I dont mind php if it can do cheers

```
 <input type="text" value='<span id="date"></span>'>
```

**Java Script**

```
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",    
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var n = new Date();
  var y = n.getFullYear();
  var m = n.getMonth();
  var d = n.getDate();
  document.getElementById("datea").innerHTML = d + " " + months[m] + " " +    
   y;
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="date" /> and spell correctly date in getElementById

Comment: @Ylber cheers buddy, i was hoping to insert the date in the value field of the form such as <input type="text" value="catch date here">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few mistake that you have made. Otherwise it is good

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var n = new Date();
var y = n.getFullYear();
var m = n.getMonth();
var d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").value = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date">
```

Comment: thanks for pointing ou the spell error but i am still working my head around it, no luck yet, what i want is the date to be inserted as a value like <input type="text" id="date" value"date here">, in this way i can catch the date and record it in my database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating your page in PHP you could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo (new DateTime())->format('j F Y'); ?>"></input>
```

Output:

```
<input type="text" value="4 August 2018"></input>
```